# ANDROID_HOME Path Set But Not Being Read

Tags: android, bash, meteor, sdk, path

Hi I've followed all the standard steps for installing Android with Meteor and am getting the following error on mup deploy:

`Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must
fulfill at least one of these conditions.`

I have entered the following into the terminal as well as into my ~/.bashrc (with and without quotes):

`export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk”
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

I can confirm the locations of those files, but am still getting the same error.

Just to make sure everything is there:

`echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk`

`echo $PATH
/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/boblikesoup/adt/sdk/tools:/Users/boblikesoup/adt/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/tools:/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yosemite made it so I have to do sudo for everything + my bash was being stores in .bash_profile instead of .bashrc unlike for many other answers.

Go to sudo mode: 
`sudo su`

`open  ~/.bash_profile`

Add:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk`

`export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH`

`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/boblikesoup/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```